# Gearman Too many open files

Tags: gearman

This question started initially as [disk space issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/732331/gearman-writing-too-many-open-files-into-the-log-disk-space-issues), however, we nailed it down to `gearman` problem. It bombs own logfile with the following message:

```
  ERROR 2015-10-29 13:05:37.000000 [  main ] accept(Too many open files) -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:
788
```

so that the log file can grow up to 70 Gb in a day. I checked the worker code: we use [node-gearman](https://github.com/andris9/node-gearman) and properly close both `mongodb` connection and gearman worker process:

```
db.close();
worker.end();
```

In the application we close gearman connection as well:

```
gearman.close();
```

This question is similar to [the other one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gearman/NnGlRdYQeDM), but there is no solution except for increasing ulimit restrictions. Even if we increase them, we don't know if we overcome the new ones soon. Need to get the reason of this.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is bug fixing of the issue in `gearmand` [v1.1.16](https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/releases/tag/1.1.16)

See also [group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gearman/AxkDVxIxMj0/xmO7mBQdBAAJ) thread to the topic